# Partial IF statement with combine multiple columns to new line, Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've hit a mental road block with a Macro. I work in the Aviation industry and am working on a wire list output CSV file. for the majority I just need to concatenate; however, for specific wire-types they are twisted pairs. and those need to be combined, to a new line.

Original output normalized layout

```
    A             C          D         F         G
WIRENAME-BLU    POINT1   LOCATION    POINT2   LOCATION
WIRANAME-WHT    POINT1   LOCATION    POINT2   LOCATION
```

Desired output after macro

```
       A          C          D          F         G
WIRENAME-BLU    POINT3   LOCATION    POINT4   LOCATION
WIRENAME-WHT    POINT1   LOCATION    POINT2   LOCATION
      A   (This can all be concat in column A.)
(WIRENAME-WHT)  POINT1LOCATION-POINT2LOCATION / BLU POINT3LOCATION-POINT4LOCATION
```

I know this can be done with concatenate, but having a struggle with the partial IF aspect of "WIRENAME".

Each wire name is structured like this,

```
    Regular wire
    12345XXX0001-WHT
    12345XXX0002-WHT
    Twisted Wires
    12345XXX0010-BLU
    12345XXX0010-WHT
```

I don't even know where to begin in with a partial if statement to combine partially match cells, and combining.

EDIT:

Sorry for the confusion, Each TwistedCable, can consist of up to four wires.

```
Each cable consists of several components. 

Harness  WireName  Color
12345    ***0001   BLU
12345    ***0001   WHT
12345    ***0001   ORG
12345    ***0001   GRN

The Cable code (0001) is going to be the same for all conductors within
the same wire. 
For instance If you had two twistedpair cables, it would be:

Harness  WireName  Color
12345    ***0001   BLU
12345    ***0001   WHT
12345    ***0002   BLU
12345    ***0002   WHT
12345    ***0015   BLU
12345    ***0015   WHT
```

Comment: So you want to match the first five characters? You could compare `LEFT(A1, 5)` with `LEFT(A2, 5)`, for example.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is the last few characters before the `-`. In both codes the first 5 characters are identical.

Comment: Jsherran, Ah, but how would that work with (xlUp) approach, the number of rows can be 10 or 1000.

Comment: Brandon, no the XXX0000, could be any three leters, followed by between 3-4 numbers. i.e. ABC1234 or CDA441. the first 5 (12345) characters will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach to this problem would be to create a formula that looks for the code related to a twisted wire. If I understand the example correctly, a twisted wire will have a code similar to this pattern:

`#####[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]0010-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]`

```
#       - Any number
[A-Z]   - Capital letters in the range of A to Z
0, 1    - Must match these numbers exactly
-       - Must match - exactly
```

Using this, we can easily check any value to see if it is a twisted pair:

```
Dim TwistedPairPattern as String
TwistedPairPattern = "#####[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]0010-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"

Dim NonTwistedCode as String
NonTwistedCode = "12345XXX0001-WHT"

Debug.Print NonTwistedCode Like TwistedPairPattern
' Result is False

Dim TwistedCode as String
TwistedCode = "12345XXX0010-BLU"

Debug.Print TwistedCode Like TwistedPairPattern
' Result is True
```

This gives you the matching logic you need, and also allows you to edit the pattern as needed.

You can read up more about the `Like` operator here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator

Or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

From there, you will just need to write the logic to use this comparison in order to create the concatenation.

EDIT: You may need to tweak the pattern based upon your comment. If I understood your comment correctly you would want something more along the lines of:

`12345[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]441*`

(I used the second pattern). This will match any code where the first 5 characters are '12345' followed by three capital letters, '441' and then zero or more characters (since it could have another number).

Comment: I didn't know I could use the Like operator like this. The wire codes are like serial numbers. NonTwistedWires will never occur twice within a given harness. TwistedWires will occur twice, or three times, due to having two conductors within a Shielding. They are signified by wht, blu, and org. I need to look for two things within the search. If its the same wire code, then how many conductors are in the wire type. I've updated the original post.

Comment: Then that changes things a bit, but also makes it a bit easier. Just split off the color code, and count occurences. If the count > 1, concat together the codes. I would recommend a dictionary for something like that.

Comment: Thanks Brandon! I'm trying to sort this out, but its really  trying my coding skills, as I'm not really sure how to even get the data-set together. This isn't typically my lane. The wires lists can consist of 1 to 1000's of wires that needs to be concatenated. This hasn't ever been a problem as older software spit this out in a format we could use. The new software doesn't do it in the same format.